# How do I update databases in sqlAlchemy and FastAPI

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

FastAPI/SQLAlchemy. I had two tables in sqlLite database: blog and user. I had created the database, but later decided to add relationship between the two and added new foreignKey Column. However, my changes did not appear in existing db (even though I deleted everything in it). Only after I deleted .db file entirely, did my --reload generate new db with new columns. I was wondering if there is analog of makemigrations + migrate from Django where you do not have to delete DB entirely for FastAPI and SQLAlchemy.

I made changes from this

```
class Blog(Base):
    __tablename__ = "blogs"
    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index= True)
    title= Column(String)
    body=Column(String)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, index=True)
    username = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    password= Column(String)
```

To this

```
class Blog(Base):
    __tablename__ = "blogs"
    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index= True)
    title= Column(String)
    body=Column(String)
    user_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id")) ### NEW 
    creator = relationship("User", back_populates= "blogs") ### NEW 

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, index=True)
    username = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    password= Column(String)
    blogs = relationship("Blog", back_populates = "creator") ### NEW
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used **alembic** to do that.

Please click this link for the official instructions! [This is the link](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-migrations/)